# How to update a column in a table with a concat of two other column from the same row for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just trying to figure out how to write a T-SQL query that allows me to update a column value (called `range`) with a concat of two values from two other columns, sequentially for each row in a table.

I've tried the following, but all it does is take the top row values in my table and updated "every" single column with the same value, regardless of range.

```
UPDATE dbo.levels
SET level_1_range = CONCAT(min_level_1, '-', max_Level_1)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
date     | min_level_1 | max_level_1 | level_1_range
---------+-------------+-------------+---------------    
01/01/18 |      1      |     10      | 1-10
02/02/18 |     20      |     25      | 20-25
```

but my code returned more like

```
date     | min_level_1 | max_level_1 | level_1_range
---------+-------------+-------------+--------------
01/01/18 |     1       |     10      | 1-10
02/02/18 |    20       |     25      | 1-10
```

Comment: your query does not matches the expected result at all. You have `level_1_range` in the query but not in the expected result. Please also show the sample data

Comment: edited the main thing to match - i'm not using real values here.

Answer (score 1):

dont see a reason for NOT using computed fields here.

```
Alter Table dbo.levels Add level_1_range_computed As CONCAT(min_level_1, '-', 
max_Level_1) PERSISTED;
```

from msdn:

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a computed column in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

A simple + will work in SQL Server, provided they are all strings. So something as simple as

```
convert(varchar,min_level_1)+'-'+convert(varchar,max_Level_1)
```

will do it.